# Facebook Open Graph - images too small

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to get images from FB open graph, which is working correctly. However the image size parameter is not, and currently I am only receiving 150x150px sized images.

The URL used in my function is as follows. Can anyone advise on how to set the actual size of the image received? Thanks

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$album_id}/photos?fields=picture&limit=4&access_token={$access_token}";

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo):

> `picture` Link to the 100px wide representation of this photo

What you probably need to get is the `images` field:

> `images` The different stored representations of the photo. Can vary in number based upon the size of the original photo.

And then you pick the image that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I can now see a multi dimensional array of different sizes, but I'm still unsure how to actually set a custom size?

Comment: I don't think you can request a custom size. You should pick from one of the sized returned